# Where do I find Traceur (ES6 Transpiler) runtime?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, traceur

I am excited about ES6 and would like warm up with it using the Traceur compiler. Here's a simple classe example:

```
require('traceur-runtime');

class Person {

    constructor(name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    greet() {
        return "Hello, I am " + this.name;
    }
}

var p1 = new Person("Luca");
p1.greet();
```

After transpiling and trying to run the example (in node), I get the following error:

> Error: Cannot find module 'traceur-runtime'

Is the runtime included in the npm installation of traceur? If yes, where is it and how do I need to include it? I cannot run the code without including the runtime...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install traceur-runtime via npm:

```
npm install traceur-runtime
```

And it should work.  Your example works for me, at least.  I compiled:

```
traceur --script test.js --out out/test.js
```

And ran:

```
node out/test.js
```

### Alternatively

You can also just install traceur:

```
npm install traceur
```

And then require it:

```
require('traceur');
```